# HP Storage Works X1400

Tags: hp

I got this error while trying to restore using the Restore DVD provided by HP. What could be the problem?

*an error occured while restoring the factory image, arrayOK: getOSPhysicalDriveForSmartArrayLogicalDrive: failed to map logical drive*

Can somebody please help??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either you have a dead disk/array or it's not configured as anticipated.

The machine is basically a HP DL320 G6 running Windows Storage Server 2008R2 on it, it only has 4 x 3.5 SATA/SAS disks and a B110i disk controller.

If you're rebuilding this from scratch, i.e. you don't care about what's on the disks right now then simply boot the machine, press F8 to enter ORCA and wipe/rebuild the array as one array with one logical drive. That should be fine but I'm going to go look at the documents ok, might be back later.

Comment: thanks! the problem was with the array controller. After resetting, it's working fine now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad you're sorted.